# Running a function once in the first click

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am trying to run a function but only in the first click, I would do it onload, but I already have another function running on `window.onload`, both functions work fine independently, but not together, so I am calling the function `window.onclick`, but I don't want the function to run in every click, is there a way to do this? Thanks in advance!

```
window.onclick = function changeURL(){
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("src", "indexT.html?ProofLoginDataRegistration="+ user);
  }
```

Comment: It would help if you add the other function that you use in `onload`, so we can see why they don't work together.

Comment: If you use `.addEventListener()` to attach event handlers, you can have as many separate handlers as you want.

Comment: ```
<script>
window.onclick = function changeURL(){
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
  document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("src", "indexT.html?ProofLoginDataRegistration="+ user);

        
    }

</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a function that calls both functions. include that in the onload event handler :D

```
window.onload = function handleOnload() 
{
   func1();
   func2();
}
```

define the other functions elsewhere, without being assigned as event handlers.

Comment: Or better: `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { func1(); func2() })` or even one at a time: `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", func1); window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", func2);` since you can have as many eventListeners you want

Answer (score 0):

You should use multiple `.addEventListers()` like so:

```
window.addEventlistener("load", function1, false);    
window.addEventlistener("load", function2, false);
```

If you use `window.onload = function1`, function2 will overwrite the first event listener.

If this still doesn't work to your specific use case, you could declare a global variable and only execute the code if that variable is true:

```js
var executeEventListener = true;

window.onclick = function changeURL() {
    if (!executeEventListener) return;
    
    var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
    document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("src", "indexT.html?ProofLoginDataRegistration="+ user);
    executeEventListener = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why does your onload not work with two functions? It sould be no problem.

Anyway, you can do it in .onClick by setting a global boolean variable ("hasClicked"). Execute the function only when the variable is false. When the user clicked the first time, set this variable to true.

E.g. something like

```
<script>
var isClicked = false;
window.onclick = function changeURL(){
    if(!isClicked){
        isClicked = true;
        alert("HI");
    }
}
</script>
```